# When checkin fails, no error message is shown. What is the reasoning behind that behavior?

Tags: tfs, versioning, user-experience

Currently, I'm once more forced to work with TFS (usually we work with SVN and GIT, depending on the project). I don't want to ramble about technology we have to use, but at least I want to understand the reasoning behind certain funcionalities or behaviors.

Now one thing that has bugged me for a long time with Team Foundation Server is, that a dialog is shown, when a check in has been successful, but when the check in failed, only the checkin dialog disappears, without notifying the user, that there has been a problem.

This behavior has led to multiple errors in our project, as files havn't been checked in and the developer simply did not notice that there was an error. The problems were caused by devs who didn't noticed that the checkin failed, but for me the real problem lies in this notification behavior.

Can somebody explain me, what the reasoning behind this notification behavior is? I'm still puzzeld (and thought a long time about it), but it does not make any sense to me. The user needs to be informed in case something goes wrong. Or am I missing something? Is it even possible to control this behavior? In all projects where I had to use TFS, I wasn't in charge of the administration, but maybe I can request a configuration change for that behavior.

Comment: It would help to know what versions are involved - the behaviours are quite different across versions, and I don't recognise the behaviour you've described (but I haven't used e.g. VS2008 for a long time)

Comment: You are right. Sorry i did not add that information, but I have to find out with the administrators, what version we are using. Or is there a way to check the version? I havn't found any version information...

Comment: You can certainly tell us what version of Visual Studio you're using. I think most of the behaviour depends on the client tools rather than the server.

Comment: Ok, i checked it with our project lead. We are using vs2010 and tfs 2010.

Comment: Do you know a scenario where no message occurs? For example if I check-in and the policies are not fulfilled, I get warnings from TFS. What I could imagine is, that you use gated-checkins (before checking in a build will be triggered) and if it fails, the sources will not be checked in and the developer didn't get any information about that.